# How to insert "nil" values into an array bound to a tableview?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'd like to have some hints about one thing:

In an array, bound to a tableview column, I have some numeric (float) values. These values are entered (put into the array) using interface buttons, labelled "0", "1", "2" and so on. There is also a "C" button to cancel an entry.

Later, I have some calculations to do with this array. If no result was entered, the array's object cannot be 0. "No value" is certainly better represented by "nil"… but you are not allowed to insert a nil object into an array (nil means "end of array").

A NSArray contains objects. That is, here, these object must be NSNumbers. So I can initialize my array by filling it with [NSNumber numberWithDouble:…] double what? I cannot put nil here!

A true NSArray does not (can not) contain "holes". But mine has to, if for example, the third item never received a value. How can I:

implement an "undefined" value for my NSNumber?
make the "C" button erase a previously entered result?

There must be a solution. In ApplescriptObjC I used a trick: I did the attribution in the method called by every button, using its title, so:

```
 if sender's title as string is "C" then
 set item theRow of gResult to missing value -- the row was the selected line, gResult was a AS list.
 else
 set item theRow of gResult to sender's title as real
 end if
```

What should I do here?
- choose a special value (say -1) to indicate an undefined value, then use a NSPredicate to filter my array?
- how could I turn the cell to "nothing" as the special value IS something and appear into the cell (even )

I'm sure there is an elegant solution to this problem. But for now I just tear out what little hair I have left…

Thank for help…

Comment: Please format code as code to improve readability. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an NSNull object to represent a null value.

Comment: If I do this, the table view shows "<null>" in the cell. That's not what an end used is to expect.

Answer (score 2):

An NSArray must always contains objects, nil is a flag indicating the end of the array. Thus in order to represent a nil value as an object you should use NSNull as follows:

```
[NSNull null]
```

Comment: If I do this, the table view shows "<null>" in the cell. Bad.

Comment: Well so you check for null and don't display it of that's the case. How are you even controlling your cells ? Doesn't sound like this is very customised at all

Comment: NO, they are simple text cells, bound to an arrayController. Note: the basic behavior of these cells is ok: they show values, which can be edited, set to a blank string to indicate "no value". My problem is to calculate with these cells. Maybe an "off-screen" array, transforming the NSString array into a NSNumber array, filtered from blank values?

Comment: I could have sworn Cocoa had a constant called NSNil, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: It could be the NSValueTransformer (NSIsNil)…

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'distinguished' object in your NSArray.  When you see that distinguished object, your code does something different.  Such a 'distinguished' object is often called a 'sentinel' and it can be anything.  For example:

```
static NSNumber *theSentinel;

/* initialize theSentinel somewhere with */
theSentinel = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: <anyfloat-doesnt'-matter-which>];
```

then in your code:

```
NSNumber *selection = [NSArray objectAtIndex: <user selection>];

if (selection == theSentinel) { /* something */ }
else { /* main */ }
```

And in your predicates you can use (in words, not code):

```
predicate = (obj NOT EQUAL theSentinel) AND (rest of your predicate based on float)
```

Comment: I think that using predicates is the best solution. I could have an "offscreen" array to do my calculations. But I'm stuck with the format of my predicate. Should be something like NSArray *myFilteredArray= [[NSArray array] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: nonNullPredicate] but how to define the format "property xy != ''"?

Comment: The documentation for NSPredicate should be your reference.  Both (NOT predicate) and operator '!=' are provided.  How to apply will depend on the details of your setup.